# Discovered, not indexed

Tags: google-index

Good afternoon! Recently I wrote a series of articles, but even when manually sent for indexing, each of them does not get into it in any way, they only appear in the report "Found, not indexed", you can tell what the matter is, here are examples of pages.

I also noticed that on July 19 I had problems with the caching plugin, after the update, as a result, this increased the response time in the console report from 250 to 650, and on the hosting I saw the load not 2-3%, but 30-40%. Apparently, the bot did not like this, and he decided not to strain the site. I have fixed this error and see that the response time is back to 250 milliseconds, as it was before the indexing issues. At the moment, I already have 12 new articles that cannot get into the index, although I see the sitemap, it is being updated in the office. Who will tell you how to explain to the bot that the load is now normal and force it to index the content?

I had an error still Missing nameservers reported by parent, but I fixed it.Examples of pages, I periodically try to send them for indexing manually via the console, but so far there is no result. it feels like they are in a queue, but the bot has not yet reached them and it is not clear when it will come.

Comment: You can't force search engines to index anything.  The best you can do is put content out there and make it as enticing as possible.

Comment: So I have already posted excellent content, tested in my practice. It is unique and I do not understand if this is a problem with google or my resource

Comment: How old is your content and how old is your site?   You need to wait at least two weeks, maybe a few months to get a page indexed even with a high reputation site.   If your entire site is new, it could take a year or two before Google trusts it enough to index most of the content.   Even established sites with tons of reputation may only get 80% or 90% of the pages with good content indexed.

Comment: The site is 7 years old, before the problems with the speed, which was 2 weeks ago, I had new pages in the index 5-10 minutes after publication. The content of the pages is excellent, I write them. With a well-deserved reputation and certifications in the area that the blog is about. I also think that you need to wait, I just assumed that there is some method to show the Google bot that everything is fine with the site in terms of performance and it can come and work normally)